# Postgres : array value must start with "{" or dimension information

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have created postgreSQL function in which i am executing the query like :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION eapar.get_eform_detail(frm_id bigint,lvl_codes text)
RETURNS TABLE(eform_detail_id bigint)
AS
$BODY$   

DECLARE
query text;
level_codes text[];
BEGIN
query := 'SELECT eform_detail_id from eform_detail where form_id='||$1||' ';

--some sql code
--$2 is lvl_codes

select into level_codes string_to_array($2, ','); --uptil here no problem

RAISE NOTICE '%',level_codes; --printing {SRV,SAA} for 'SRV,SAA'::text

query:= query || 'AND level_code = ANY('''||level_codes||''') '; --problem area

--remaining sql code
```

Function has been created successfully but when i am calling like:

```
select * from eapar.get_eform_detail(265,'SRV,SAA'::text)
```

It gives the error:

```
ERROR:  array value must start with "{" or dimension information
LINE 1: ...orm_detail || 'AND level_code = ANY('''||level_codes||''') '
```

I am new to postgres functions. Don't know how to substitute array of text into variable using ANY operator, and get it executed. Please help. Thank you

Comment: I think you might just need an explicit cast from array to string -  `'...' || level_codes::text || '...'` - the `||` operator is overloaded for arrays so it may be interpreting it differently.

Comment: Superb!!  It works. I was finding solution since morning. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad it worked. I've posted it as an answer so that it's more obvious for anyone in future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string formatting returned by the `RAISE NOTICE` looks correct, so I'm guessing the `||` operator is not forcing the value to text. This might be because it is overloaded with a different meaning for arrays, so is misinterpreting your intention.

Try with an explicit cast:

```
query:= query || 'AND level_code = ANY('''||level_codes::text||''') ';
```